# UPSERT an edge with properties with Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm trying to upsert an edge (insert if it does not exist but update if it does) with properties in Gremlin via a single query.

I have this which adds a `manages` edge with a `duration` property between two vertices with id of `Amy` and `John`.

`g.E().where(outV().has('id','Amy')).where(inV().has('id','John')).fold().coalesce(unfold(),g.V('Amy').as('a').V('John').addE('manages').from('a').property('duration','1year'))`.

The query does do an upsert, but if I change the value of the `duration` property, remove the `duration` property, or add other properties, the property changes are not reflected on the edge.

I want to be able to change the value of the `duration` property without adding a new edge or having to remove the old one.

I'm fairly new to Gremlin so please share any advice which may help.

I'm not sure it matters but the underlying DB is an Azure Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two additions to [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70654151/17897170):

1. I think you need to specify the edge label in `outE`, otherwise the `unfold` may return other relationships present between the two vertices, and these will be updated with the property, rather than triggering the addE of the new edge. Specifying the edge label should ensure the length of the folded array is 0 in the case of INSERT and 1 in the case of UPDATE.
2. For Cosmos DB Gremlin API, use the anonymous class `__` when not using `g`

```
g.V('Amy').
  outE('manages').where(inV().hasId('John')).
  fold().
  coalesce(
    unfold(),
    __.addE('manages').from(__.V('Amy')).to(__.V('John'))).
  property('duration', '1year')
```

More detailed example [here](https://gist.github.com/lindacmsheard/c0273e272045911e9745dd52b864c12b).

Comment: Linda, thank you for your help, I will check it out later today and report back on whether it solves my problem or not.

Comment: I tried both code samples and this one worked first time. Thank you both Linda and Kevin for your input

Answer (score 2):

To always have the property change apply whether the edge exists or is created, you just need to move the `property` step to after the `coalesce`:

```java
g.E().
  where(outV().has('id', 'Amy')).
  where(inV().has('id', 'John')).
  fold().
  coalesce(
    unfold(),
    g.V('Amy').as('a').
      V('John').
      addE('manages').from('a')).
   property('duration', '1year')
```

However, that said, there are a few observations that can be made about the query. Starting with `g.E()` is likely to be inefficient and using `g.V()` mid traversal should be avoided, and where necessary just `V()` used.

If 'John" and 'Amy' are unique ID's you should take advantage of that along these lines:

```java
g.V('Amy').
  outE().where(inV().hasId('John')).
  fold().
  coalesce(
    unfold(),
    addE('manages').from(V('Amy')).to(V('John'))).
  property('duration', '1year')
```

**UPDATED 2023-03-17**

In TinkerPop release 3.6.0 two new steps `mergeV` and `mergeE` were added to Gremlin. These are designed to make the "create if not exist" or "upsert" type queries much easier to write. In most cases these new steps will replace the former `fold...coalesce` pattern. If the database you are using supports at least that TinkerPop version queries like the ones discussed in this post become simpler to write.  For further reading please checkout the [TinkerPop documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#mergevertex-step)

Comment: Kelvin, thank you for your help, I will check it out later today and report back on whether it solves my problem or not.